# Which football team has spent the most money buying players over the last decade?

Tags: football, trivia, transfer

Which football club in the world has spent the most amount of money over the past 10 years?

Answer (score 1):

Manchester City has spent the most in football transfers in this decade followed by Barcelona, Chelsea, Juventus, PSG and Real Madrid. Although the net transfers are completely different. Here is a link to the total net transfers done by the clubs:

[Highest net Transfers](https://www.transfermarkt.co.in/transfers/einnahmenausgaben/statistik/plus/0?ids=a&sa=&saison_id=2010&saison_id_bis=2019&land_id=&nat=&pos=&altersklasse=&w_s=&leihe=&intern=0)